# Readings on Dark Matter

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, dark-matter

I am looking for introductions and reviews (papers or books) on the possible observation and the nature of dark matter. This [book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Particle-Dark-Matter-Observations-Searches/dp/0521763681/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=Particle%20Dark%20Matter%20Observations%2C%20Models%20and%20Searches&qid=1593765370&sr=8-1) seems to be a good start, but I would be grateful for any other recommendations  that are accessible to people with knowledge of physics at the undergraduate level.

Comment: @Qmechanic I understand that duplicated questions are deleted, and I was actually aware of that question before posting mine. But surely you would agree that this is a nine year old question and new resources should be available now.

Comment: Hi @ Floyd: Welcome to Phys.SE. Technically duplicated questions are closed rather than deleted. Note that res. recom. qs. are restricted on Phys.SE.

Comment: Where can one ask such recommendation questions

Comment: @AarushiAgarwal try physicsforums.com